# Can I add actions to control automator to automator?

Tags: applescript, automator

Is there any way that I can add automator itself to the list of services I can automate? For example right now I can go and add a launch application action to the workflow and within that action launch automator. Effectively this creates a level of control over automator but only by routing it through the utilities action item. I know that you can add new application action libraries to automator to control any app that releases a library for it. So is there one for automator? Where is it if there is?

Answer (score 1):

Automator itself does not ship with self referencing Automator actions.

## GUI Scripting

Alternative approaches include using GUI Scripting to automate interactions with the Automator application. See [Accessibility Preferences and GUI Scripting](http://www.macosxautomation.com/mavericks/guiscripting/index.html) for an example of how to set this up on recent versions of Mac OS X.

## automator Command Line Tool

OS X includes an [automator](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/automator.1.html) command line tool. You can use this tool to incorporate your Automator workflows into other scripts. Through this tool you can pass in variables and thus manipulate the workflow's behaviour.

## Beyond Automator

You may find GUI Scripting and the corresponding **What Me Do** action [fragile or unpredictable](http://www.dssw.co.uk/blog/2014-11-10-automator-watch-me-do/index.html). If so, consider tools such as [Sikuli](http://www.sikuli.org) to help automate your Mac.